# R fread() error when executing multiple scripts

Tags: r, fread, slurm, rscript

edit:
the file path i am giving is not /tmp/...

the file path is in the form of:
Erfurt/phased_edited_all_chr.gz

i think the tmp directory is created by Slurm, but not sure about it.
end edit.

I am working on a data analysis project, and have a script that use this command:

`haps_file <- fread(HAPS, drop=c(2), colClasses = list(integer = 1:3, character = 4:5))`

i run this script about 30~ times with the same HAPS input (but other changes to the script).
HAPS is a gzip file of about 200 Mb

Most of the times it runs OK.
Three of the times (33) it resulted with this error:

> Error in fread(HAPS, drop = c(2), colClasses = list(integer = 1:3, character = 4:5)) :
> File is empty: /tmp/Rtmp998Hni/file9cde5383550b

The scripts are executed with slurm using a bash command.

Any idea what happens here? Each job works from a different core and it should work.
Any idea how to solve the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since the location is in `/tmp`, the OS might be cleaning it every so often -

https://serverfault.com/questions/377348/when-does-tmp-get-cleared/377349

Can you try moving the file location out of `/tmp`?

Comment: the file is located on the university servers. the path i enter there is a path to my folder on that server. i think the /tmp location is created for the job itself by the slurm clusters? i dont really know. the path itself is more like /vol/sci/.../phased_edited_all_chr.gz